# kea-dhcp4-server doesn't work after a restart of the raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have installed `kea-dhcp4-server` on my `raspberry pi3 b+`.
I configured everything on the `/etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf` but there is a problem.
When I restart the raspberry kea no longer responds to dhcp request so I run `sudo service kea-dhcp4-server status` that show me this

```
● kea-dhcp4-server.service - ISC KEA IPv4 DHCP daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-03-04 12:08:52 CET; 5min ago
     Docs: man:kea-dhcp4(8)
 Main PID: 415 (kea-dhcp4)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 10.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kea-dhcp4-server.service
           └─415 /usr/sbin/kea-dhcp4 -c /etc/kea/kea-dhcp4.conf

Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
Mar 04 12:08:53 rasp1 kea-dhcp4[415]: Unable to use interprocess sync lockfile (No such file or directory): /var/run/kea/isc_kea_logger_lockfile
```

I have to create the folder with `sudo mkdir /var/run/kea/` and then restart the service with `sudo service kea-dhcp4-service restart` to make it works. But if I restart the raspberry again the problem reoccurs.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also using kea on a Raspberry Pi and I solved it by creating `/var/run/kea` every time systemd starts kea.

To do so, do the following:

1. Copy the kea systemd-unit file to /etc/systemd/system

   `cp /lib/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service /etc/systemd/system`

   Copying over this unit file makes sure that it won't be overwritten by the next update of the kea package.
2. Add the following to the `[Service]`-Section of this file: (`/etc/systemd/system/kea-dhcp4-server.service`)

   ```
   ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/kea
   ```

   This command gets executed before systemd starts kea and it will create the missing directory.
3. Execute `systemctl daemon-reload`. This will make systemd notice the new configuration.

Reboot and you should be good to go.